# Nhibernate many-to-one mapping returning duplicate values

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, orm

I have a master table `PURCHASE BILL MASTER` and a child table `PURCHASE BILL DETAILS`.
I have written an impl in child table to get the data as follows:

```
 public IList<PurchaseBillDetails> GetDetailsByInvDate(string FrmDate, string ToDate, int ShopId, int DeptId, int DrugId)
    {
        ICriteria Query = SessionFactory
       .GetCurrentSession()
       .CreateCriteria(typeof(PurchaseBillDetails))
       .CreateAlias("PurchaseBillMaster", "PBM");
                   if (FrmDate != string.Empty && FrmDate != null)
        {
            Query.Add(Restrictions.Gt("PBM.InvoiceDate", Convert.ToDateTime(FrmDate)));
        }
        if (ToDate != string.Empty && ToDate != null)
        {
            Query.Add(Restrictions.Lt("PBM.InvoiceDate", Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate)));
        }
        if (ShopId != 0)
        {
            Query.Add(Restrictions.Like("PBM.ShopNo", ShopId));
        }
        if (DeptId != 0)
        {
            Query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("PBM.DeptId", DeptId));
        }
        if (DrugId != 0)
        {
            Query.Add(Restrictions.Like("DrugId", DrugId));
        }

        Query.Add(Restrictions.Eq("HospitalId", Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["HospitalId"])));
        //Query.AddOrder(Order.Desc("BillDate"));
        IList<PurchaseBillDetails> list = Query.List<PurchaseBillDetails>();
        return list;
    }
```

*i have written a mapping like this :*

```
<many-to-one name="PurchaseBillMaster" class="Validus.Pharmacy.Domain.PurchaseBillMaster, HIS.Pharmacy"  column="PURCHASE_BILL_ID" insert="false" update="false"></many-to-one>
```

but the problem is it returning the repeated values once that is  physically table has 3 rows in the given date ,but the impl is giving 33 because each row is repeated so many times.

How to get the unique rows.Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your criteria that it should filter out non-unique entities by using the `DistinctRootEntity` entity-transformer.

```
Query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
IList<PurchaseBillDetails> list = Query.List<PurchaseBillDetails>();
```

Next to that, I'd like to see the definition of your entity, and more specifically the many-to-many relationship.
Are you using a List or a Set for this relationship ?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply my many to one relation ship is as follows :

<many-to-one name="PurchaseBillMaster" class="Validus.Pharmacy.Domain.PurchaseBillMaster, HIS.Pharmacy"  column="PURCHASE_BILL_ID" insert="false" update="false"></many-to-one>

Comment: But is the collection -in your class- a list or a set ?